# Set legend over colorbar in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to have the legend (of some contours) over the colorbar of a surf plot.
How can I have a layout similar to the image in a figure plot?
From the black

```
colorbar;
legend('label1','label2','Location','northeastoutside');
```

to the red one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the position of both the colorbar and the legend

```
% Make a demo plot
figure(); hold on
plot( rand(20,3) ); % lines for the legend
peaks(10);          % surface for the colorbar
view(3);            % 3D view

% Create a legend and colorbar, retain their handles
L = legend( 'show', 'location', 'eastoutside' );
C = colorbar();

% Get some key variables from the current position of the colorbar/legend
% -> avg mid point of colorbar and legend
x = ( L.Position(1) + (C.Position(1)+C.Position(3)) ) / 2; 
% -> Max width of the two objects
w = max( L.Position(3), C.Position(3) );
% -> A nominal y value and padding to dictate the spacing
y = 0.1;
pad = 0.05;

% Move the legend and colorbar
% First move the x/y coords of the legend to be on top, centred around common x
L.Position(1:2) = [x - L.Position(3)/2, 1 - y - L.Position(4)];
% Then move the x/y coords of the colorbar to be on the bottom, centred around common x
C.Position(1:2) = [x - C.Position(3)/2, y]; 
% Then resize the colorbar to use the vertical space not utilised by the legend
C.Position(4) = L.Position(2) - pad - y;

% By moving the legend/colorbar the axes will have "popped" to use the full width
% Need to move it to span between the current left edge and the newly moved leg/colorbar
ax = gca();
ax.Units = 'Norm';
ax.Position(3) = (x-w/2) - pad - ax.Position(1) ;
```

Result:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this interactively by clicking the "Cursor" icon in the top of the plot window and adjusting the legend/colorbar. Once you have finished editing choose "Generate Code" in the "File" menu of the plot window to have code generated so you can repeatedly create the plot.